# Vulkan error VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED when trying to get physical devices

Tags: c++, vulkan

## **Situation**

I wrote a simple c++ code with VulkanAPI, but however I'm getting errors when I'm trying to get my physical devices.

## **Hardware/Software**

OS: **elementary OS 5.1.3 Hera x86_64**

Notebook model: **80Q5 Lenovo G70-35**

CPU: **AMD A8-6410 APU with AMD Radeon R5 Graphics (4) @ 2.000**

GPU: **AMD Radeon R4/R5 Graphics**

You can find the list of supported devices [here](https://www.amd.com/en/technologies/vulkan) (I think)

## **Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vulkan/vulkan.h"

VkInstance instance;

void assert(VkResult result) {
   if (result != VK_SUCCESS)
        std::cout << "error: " << result << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    VkApplicationInfo appInfo;
    appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    appInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    appInfo.pApplicationName = "VulkanAPI";
    appInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(0, 0, 0);
    appInfo.pEngineName = "VulkanAPI Engine";
    appInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(0, 0, 0);
    appInfo.apiVersion = VK_API_VERSION_1_2;

    VkInstanceCreateInfo instanceInfo;
    instanceInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    instanceInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    instanceInfo.flags = 0;
    instanceInfo.pApplicationInfo = &appInfo;
    instanceInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;
    instanceInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = nullptr;
    instanceInfo.enabledExtensionCount = 0;
    instanceInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = nullptr;

    VkResult result = vkCreateInstance(&instanceInfo, nullptr, &instance);
    assert(result); // works fine

    uint32_t physicalDevicesCount = 0;
    result = vkEnumeratePhysicalDevices(instance, &physicalDevicesCount, nullptr);
    assert(result); // prints -3, which is equivalent to VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED

    std::cout << physicalDevicesCount << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

## **Problem**

Whenever I compile and run this code it throws/prints an error:

**-3** (which is **[VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkResult.html)**)

Comment: May be try with lower API like VK_API_VERSION_1_0, try to reinstall your graphic card driver.

Comment: Preferably, do not crosspost. Linking the questions together: https://community.khronos.org/t/vulkan-error-vk-error-initialization-failed-when-trying-to-get-physical-devices/105634

Comment: @krOoze If You want, You can post Your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per internet your GPU AMD Radeon R5 M330 is Sea Islands generation.

The `radv` vulkan driver requires the new `amdgpu` kernel miniport driver. But Sea Islands and Southern Islands GPUs by default still run on the legacy `radeon` kernel driver. The `amdgpu` driver support for them is "experimental".

To enable the support you must add kernel parameters that make `radeon` driver to refuse the GPU and `amdgpu` to accept it.

For Southern Islands that is `radeon.si_support=0 amdgpu.si_support=1`.
For Sea Islands it is `radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1`.

You can find how to add kernel parameters e.g. at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters.